# Young adult/teen maybe children's? Book about a clone (Thriller?)

Tags: story-identification, books, clones

This is going to be such a vague description of the plot so I apologize, but I had a wave of nostalgia from watching a youtube video where I remembered this book.

Basically, it's a young teen boy who hates doing chores and homework and instead loves watching tv in the den and playing baseball. He clones himself and convinces his clone to do the homework and chores while he just watches tv. Then, things take a turn for the worse because the clone wants to go outside and play baseball and do things so they start flipping coins? to see who gets to do the chores and homework and who gets to have fun.

Eventually, there are several clones of the boy, and I think they want to kill him or something?

Comment: When did you read this book, and when do you think it was published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I identified the book. *[Three Faces of Me](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18799574-three-faces-of-me)* (2012) by R.L. Stine.

> When Ira Fishman wins a prize in the machine outside a candy store, he’s disappointed it’s not the squirt gun he had his eye on. The little black plastic box looks like a camera, but when Ira presses the green button on top, nothing happens.
>
> After dinner that night, Ira can’t believe what he sees in his room: a boy with the same clothes—and face—as Ira! He tries to get this second Ira to leave, but it’s no use. Deciding to have a little fun, Ira makes the boy go to school in his place—but it’s a disaster. The new Ira isn’t good at math like the real Ira, and he’s horrible at softball. Worst of all, he plays with the girls during recess! Ira’s clone is ruining his rep—fast. And when a third Ira shows up, Ira number one has to find a way to make the others disappear for good before his whole world is turned upside down. But how do you get rid of *yourself*?

Comment: Very nice! Though it would be even better if you [edit]ed in some of the details that match what you remembered

Answer (score 5):

Might this be *[The Duplicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Duplicate)* (1988) by William Sleator?

Apparently the boy and the first duplicate do flip a coin to decide who has to do what, and there does end up being more than one duplicate in total.

> The main character, David, finds a device at the beach that can duplicate any living organism. After testing the device on his pet fish, David makes a clone of himself so that he could go on a date with his crush, Angela, while his clone attends his grandmother's birthday. His plan backfires because the Duplicate believes himself to be the original, and refuses to take orders. **David ends up having to go to his grandmothers birthday after he loses a coin toss to the duplicate**.
>
> **David's real problems begin when the Duplicate uses the device to create a clone of himself. The new duplicate is a less-than-perfect reproduction, being a copy of a copy**, and has goals and desires that differ from the original David. Eventually, the second duplicate turns on Angela and the original David, and he has to find a way to stop him. Later, he stumbles upon something that will change his life.

According to [this summary](https://www.risingshadow.net/library/book/15471-the-duplicate), one of the duplicates also wants the original boy dead.

> When David finds a mysterious machine that can copy living things, he thinks his problems are over. Now he can be in two places at once: at his grandmother's and out on a date. While the other David is in school, the real one can spend the day at the beach. The possibilities are endless. And they turn terrifying. **David's duplicate has a mind, ideas, and desires of his own – and one of them is to see the real David dead.**

Comment: I don't think this is the one. I don't remember anything about an Angela or a grandmother in this story I read

Comment: I just read this book, and it's not the book I can confirm it's not the book I have in mind. In this book, there is no mention of the original boy enjoying watching television or playing baseball.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like *Me Two* by Mary C Ryan as per [YA/children's fiction about a mail-order clone](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186677/ya-childrens-fiction-about-a-mail-order-clone)

> It's about a 13-year-old boy named Wilf Farkus who orders OceanPups for a school science project (where OceanPups are probably a lot like Sea-Monkeys). The lab that sells OceanPups made a mistake, so Wilf inadvertently cloned himself. The clone went to school for Wilf and did very well. It seems that the geneticists at the lab found out about the accidental clone, and tried to do evil things to cover up. In the end, Wilf's parents decided to let the clone live with them, claiming he was Wilf's cousin Steve.

Comment: This isn't it. The parents never found out about this clone in my story.